# Map JSON with keys containing colons

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a nice way to map this JSON to a Java object?

```
{
    "entries": {
        "prefix:someId": {
            "name": "prefix:someId",
            "type": "ID"
        }
    }
}
```

Wouldn't the property names of the Java object have to contain the colons, as well? This is not allowed in Java, obviously.

I am using JSONPath at the moment, but would like a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can use the `@JsonProperty` annotation to map a different JSON property name to a Java property.

Comment: Thanks, will use that!